# Writing Junit test case file upload controller

Tags: file, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am writing test case for file upload controller. I need to pass value in the URL. I need some help.

```
@Test
public void testHandleFileUpload() throws Exception {

    //String fileType = "Seller";
    InputStream uploadStream = PALFileUploadController.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("");
    MockMultipartFile file = new MockMultipartFile("file", uploadStream);
    assert uploadStream != null;

    this.mockMvc.perform(( fileUpload("/uploadFile/{fileType}"))
            .file(file))
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

The error message I see when running this code is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not enough variable values available to expand 'fileType'
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents$VarArgsTemplateVariables.getValue(UriComponents.java:327)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expandUriComponent(UriComponents.java:230)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents$FullPathComponent.expand(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:685)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:328)
at org.springframework.web.util.HierarchicalUriComponents.expandInternal(HierarchicalUriComponents.java:47)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponents.expand(UriComponents.java:163)
at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.buildAndExpand(UriComponentsBuilder.java:412)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.<init>(MockHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:122)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.<init>(MockMultipartHttpServletRequestBuilder.java:52)
at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload(MockMvcRequestBuilders.java:201)
at com.ibm.finance.palink.web.test.PALFileUploadControllerTest.testHandleFileUpload(PALFileUploadControllerTest.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

But I know I need to pass value as "Seller" or "Approver" for fileType.

Please tell me How to pass value to fileType variable.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your controller code, it is difficult to answer, but I'm assuming that your controller looks something like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile/{fileType}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void fileUpload(@RequestParam MultipartFile file, @PathVariable String fileType) {
    // ...
}
```

Your test should be something like:

```
mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.fileUpload("/uploadFile")
    .file(file)
    .param("fileType", "Seller")
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

Comment: My controller looks as you mentioned. And this is working for me. thanks Paul.